# conversion from visual c++ 2008 to visual c++ 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I need some help regarding my project. I have a project which is Micrsosoft Visual c++ 2008 and i want to convert it in visual c++ 6.0.

Is there any converter available which convert from visual c++ 2008 to visual c++ 6.0 or we 
do it manually?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to convert? VC++6 is an obsolete and not standard comliant

Answer (score 0):

There is a [converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/prjconverter/) for VC++7 (aka Visual-C++ 2002) down to VC++6, based on this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/prjconverter.aspx)

I think the format of project/solution file hasn't changed between 2002 and 2008, so it might be worth trying. If you get errors try to modify the project file manually, and find out (sources are provided) what's wrong.